# MOSFET circuit truth table

Tags: mosfet, nand

In the attached image you can find a simple circuit with two self blocking N channel MOSFETs. If the gate is powered they conduct. So my truth table looks like a AND operation. Why is this wrong? Why is it a NAND operation?

[image]

Comment: How do you define *true* for \$A\$ and \$B\$, how for \$Y\$? (`my truth table looks like…` present it in the question.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a NAND because when both inputs are at logical 1, both MOSFETs conduct (thus shorting the output to 0 volts) and the output is therefore logical 0. That is a NAND and not an AND operation.

Comment: why is this shorting the output to 0 volts? @andy-aka

Comment: That is what n-channel MOSFETs will do when operated in common source. You activate the gate with a positive signal with respect to their source terminal and, the drain-source channel becomes highly conductive thus, shorting the output to 0 volts @Robert